# Using System.out.println() with loops and arrays

Tags: java, array, loops

Is there anyway I can create a loop for System.out.println("...") and reading in the values? For example I wish to do this:

```
    System.out.println("Input the Executive's name: ");
    String eName = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Input the Executive's address: ");
    String eAddress = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Input the Employee's name: ");
    String emName = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Input the Employee's address: ");
    String emAddress = input.nextLine();
```

However, I want to do it for volunteers, staff, human resources, and miscellaneous staff. I don't want to create so many System.out.println and have to read so many variables in. Is there any way I can create a loop or an array to make this more clean and concise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use map with key value pairs.

Give a try to this:

```
java.util.Map<String,String> contacts = new java.util.HashMap<>();
for (String key : new String[]{"Executive's name", "Executive's address", "Employee's name", "Employee's address"}){
    System.out.println("Input the " + key + ": ");
    contacts.put(key, input.nextLine());
}
```